# What does "prompting" for an integer mean?

Tags: c++, int, 32-bit

I have the following question on my test review:

> You are to write a program to do the following:
>
> - Prompt the user for a 32-bit integer number entered as text via the console
> - Determine if the number is prime
> - Output either the phrase “prime” or “not prime” as appropriate

I'm confused about the prompting for a 32-bit integer. Is that the same as declaring a normal int variable?

Comment: prompting for an 32bit integer means "ask the user to enter a 32bit integer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer: no. Longer answer: possibly yes.

Why? `int` doesn't have fixed size; it's defined as having *at least* 16 bits. It might just happen to have 32 bits, but it isn't guaranteed. Use `int32_t` or `uint32_t` for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

it means you need add following 2 line code

```
cout << "input a 32 bit integer";
cin >> i
```

then i the number you got from prompt.

and the question comment is correct, you ask user for a 32 bit number.

Answer (score 1):

Using `uint32_t` should be more accurate. `int` can be different from 32-bit in some architectures.